# Error while uploading image file to server

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to upload a selected image from the image viewer to the server using a web service.

My web service requires user Id, pwd and filename as a request.

But when I run, I am getting error for the filename.

Error says "procedure requires filename which was not supplied". Though I am passing filename here.

Can anybody please look at the code and let me know, what could be the problem? - Thanks.

```
NSData *imageData;
imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 90);   

//creating the url request:
NSURL *postUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myURL"];
NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:postUrl];

//adding header information:
[postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *stringBoundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];
[postRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

//setting up the body:
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userid\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"100"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pwd\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"pwd"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"1.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

// now lets make the connection to the web
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString *returnString;
returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
lblLoginStatus.text = @"Uploading done.";

NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
```

Comment: I just spent a couple of days trying to get images uploading onto server, there's really a lot of variables. It could be problems on the server side instead of iOS side.

May I suggest a couple of things? 
1. Comment out the following line: 
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
2. Add content length like: 
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

Answer (score 0):

In your other fields you have two times `\r\n` in your format string, in the filename entry only one. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this but it did not help. I see the same error.

Comment: I am almost sure that is the line that creates the problem. I am not sure I understand your formatting with the `;` to separate parameters. I recommend checking the logic of that in your web form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:   Although its uploading Audio but should work in the same way.

```
NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        destinationFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@/audio.mp3", documentsDirectory];
        progress.myLabel.text = @"Uploading file...";
        [self.view addSubview:progress.view];
        NSLog(@"will upload file: %@", destinationFilePath);
        NSString * text = captionText;
        //this one works
        // try this with dataWithContentOfURL
        NSData *audioData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
        NSLog(@"File URL:%@",fileURL);

    NSString * urlString = @"urlstring"


    // setting up the request object now
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


    NSArray *myArray = [destinationFilePath componentsSeparatedByString: @"/"];
    NSString *fileName = (NSString*)[myArray lastObject];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"action\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"upload" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"code\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSString *strkCode = @"code";

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", strkCode] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:audioData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    if (![text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",@"caption"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    [audioData release];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"error connecting!");
    }
    [connection release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this code. I have URL string to upload.

In your code, what is "destinationFilePath"?

NSArray *myArray = [destinationFilePath componentsSeparatedByString: @"/"];